Incorrect display of push icons on androids from version 12 onwards. Ionic, cordova
Project angular cordova. There is a problem with push icons. I have specified in config.xml the paths to the icons. https://pastebin.com/LnWirY4L . I had it like this for a long time, more than half a year, but now it stopped working.
I'm building android, the icons of the application installation, the icon on the desktop - ok, but the icons of pooches are not quite correct. In particular, on the top panel in general white circle. The problem starts on phones with android 12 and more, on older phones everything is ok.
Apparently Google has changed something there and now the application of icons should be done somehow differently. I checked one and the same apk, which had the correct push icons three months ago and now I install the same apk on phones with version 12 or 13 and instead of the push icon on the top panel there is a white circle or square and the push itself is a turquoise circle with a white square inside. It seems that I am not the only one with the same problem.
Judging by the description of https://docs.wonderpush.com/docs/change-icon-and-color, it seems that this variant should work:
In config.xml, write three png:
<resource-file src="resources/android/icon_adaptive/mdpi-push.png" target="/app/src/main/res/drawable/mdpi_push.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/icon_adaptive/hdpi-push.png" target="/app/src/main/res/drawable/hdpi_push.png" />
    <resource-file src="resources/android/icon_adaptive/xhdpi-push.png" target="/app/src/main/res/drawable/xhdpi_push.png" />

Then in AndroidManifest.xml:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/mdpi_push" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.notification_channel_icon" android:resource="@drawable/hdpi_push" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.notification_big_icon" android:resource="@drawable/xhdpi_push" />

Everything is assembled without errors, but instead of the push icon there is still a white circle on androids since version 12.What am I missing? What is the correct way to write paths to icons and what size icons should be in the end?
